# rails active record value_of method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I start working on project with long history and find a lot queries
like:

```
 Users.where(:test => false).value_of(:id)
```

which returns array like [1,2,66,32]

I try use this code on new project with Rails 3.2.8 but this method seems to be provided with some gem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be valium gem https://github.com/ernie/valium

Answer (score 0):

But you should replace for [`ActiveRecord::Calculations#pluck`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck)

`Users.where(test: false).pluck(:id)`

Comment: and remove valium dependency